# How can you destructure an array of objects in Javascript into two predefined variables in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have an array containing one object of this form : 
Array = [ { type: type, message: message } ]

I keep getting ESLint errors asking me to use object destructuring and array destructuring.

Currently my code looks like this :

```
let type=null;
let message=null;
if (data.length > 0) {
  ({ type, message } = data[0]);
}
```

So far this works and my variables are assigned correctly, however I am still getting the "Use array destructuring" message from ESLint.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `let [{ type, message }] = data` though I really hate that

Comment: I don't want to do that because if the data array is empty, I want the type and message variables to stay equal to null :(

Comment: @VittorioGuerrera If the array is empty, the destructuring line is not even executed because of your `if `?

Comment: @VittorioGuerrera Then use default values

Comment: Oh right sorry guys, it's too early in the morning where I am, so far these all work. Thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure the array:

```
let type=null;
let message=null;
if (data.length > 0) {
  [{ type, message }] = data;
}
```

The code above is a shorter version of:

```
[ firstElement ] = data;  // array destructruring
({ type, message } = firstElement);  // object destructuring
```

Comment: This seems to have worked ! Do you think you can tell me why ? Lets say the array had more than one object, how would I have done it then ?

Comment: It works even there is more than one object in array.

Comment: @V1cst3r - As Faly says, this works fine if there are other objects in the array. It won't grab their properties, of course; this only looks at the first object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

[Faly's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627491/157247) is good. You can also use default values when destructuring:

```js
function test(label, data) {
  // 1 -----------------------------vvvvv
  let [{type = null, message = null} = {}] = data;
  // 2 -----^^^^^^^---------^^^^^^^
  console.log(label, type, message);
}
test("test1: ", []);
test("test2: ", [{type: "t"}]);
test("test3: ", [{type: "t", message: "m"}]);
```

That works because if `data.length` is `0`, `data[0]` is `undefined`, and so triggers use of the default value `{}` (1) for the array part of that; within the object part of that, we use `null` (2) to handle any missing values on the object as well.

Answer (score 1):

EsLint wants you to write

```
let type = null;
let message = null;
if (data.length > 0) {
  [{ type, message }] = data;
}
```

which destructures the first item of an iterable `data` into the `{type, message}` target. (More items are ignored).

I would however recommend to use default values for the empty case:

```
const [{type, message} = {type:null, message:null}] = data;
```

or also

```
const [{type = null, message = null} = {}] = data;
```

Comment: `const [{type, message} = {type:null, message:null}] = data;` risks getting `undefined` instead of `null` if the object is present but doesn't have the related property (which is why I used the second one :-) ).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder …which risks getting `null` instead of `undefined` if the object is present and has the respective property with the desired value `undefined`. Neither is exactly equivalent to the verbose one with the `if` statement. I don't think it matters.